# Introduce a compile time error and suppress the error afterwards in C macros (C/ObjC)

Tags: objective-c, c, macros

You may embed a compile time error in a C macro with the `_Pragma`:

```
#define IntroduceCompileTimeError \
    _Pragma("GCC error(\"error message here.\")");
```

But I want to introduce a compile time error and suppress the error later by C macros, to ensure that the pair macros exist, how can I do that? For example:

```
BeginTaskMacro  // This macro will introduce a compile time error to notify that you should invoke `EndTaskMacro` later.

... // Do something

EndTaskMacro  // This macro will suppress the compile time error.
```

Comment: Interesting question, but as a practical matter why not just remove "BeginTaskMacro" when you're done with the task?

Comment: Are you using GCC or Clang?

Comment: @Josh Caswell: I need to do something in the `BeginTaskMacro` and `EndTaskMacro`. I'm using LLVM compiler with Clang.